# Landing page takes time to load/show

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I built an Angular application. I am building a project using the below command:

```
ng build --env=staging --target=production --aot=false
```

Result:

```
Hash: 7e7b9c4eecc155819498
Time: 111448ms
chunk {0} polyfills.149a820f76eebb0aa731.bundle.js (polyfills) 65.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.446a848fec514fd227a0.bundle.js (main) 1.19 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.764f989c6e8171fc8bab.bundle.css (styles) 127 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.21b3dcaa9a7f0ffad906.bundle.js (vendor) 3.16 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.0c2d7dbea7a8d2a649ad.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

Issue is when I deploy my application on server and load/hit the main page URL, it takes 17-18s to show. I checked the network tab. Below are the 2 main things that are taking time:

- `main.446a848fec514fd227a0.bundle.js` = 9-10s
- `vendor.21b3dcaa9a7f0ffad906.bundle.js` = 5-6s

How can I reduce this time? Goal is < 5s.

Comment: Ahead of time (AOT) compilation helps reduce overall size, so it's unclear why you've turned it *off*, but beyond that: faster internet? You could also look into lazy loading some of the modules.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can do:

**Enable Gzip**
If your web server allows you to make that change, Gzip will already compress the bundle.js files, resulting in smaller files to download

**Enable AOT**
I see that you're setting it to false. You should enable it. It will precompile your code, resulting in 2 main benefits:
- no Angular compiler in js files, so smaller download
- no compilation done at render time, so faster rendering

**The -prod option**
The *-prod* option when building will tree-shake your code. It will remove unused portions of source and library code, again resulting in smaller bundle.js files.

**Bonus: Lazy Load Modules**
Since it's just a landing page, you most likely don't have multiple modules. But if one day you do, it's a good practice to load your modules only when required to reduce startup time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am getting errors when I enable --aot option.

(relative path: ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Any idea?